# Entity field with attribute value equal to other input [PHP] [Symfony]

Tags: php, symfony

The idea is simple but can't find the way to do it.

I have a form where I have some fields and 2 of them are entity fields petType(dog, cat etc) and breed (labrador etc). I want to choose my petType and then be able to chose only those breeds which fit to type.

This is my form which I use to create pet;
[image]

Form in action;

[image]

As you can see form is generated correctly, it takes data from database and it submit ok and add new pet without any problems.

The question is how to make it that if I choose a type (rodzaj) I will see only those breeds (rasa) which suits to it.

I know that probably it is possible to do it with some ifs but I think there must be some option which I can add to my FormBuilder.

Also the breed have PetType in relation ManyToOne so the breed know which type it is but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use javascript that refreshes the options of dropdown 2 if a change has been made to dropdown 1. You need a separate AJAX action in your controller that renders the options html only. then with javascript (I prefer Jquery) make an AJAX call to that action and place the response between the  and  of dropdown 2.